# Как написать рассылку для Telegram бота на Telebot Python

Tags: python, telebot, рассылка

Задача: написать рассылку для бота с запросом ввести текст перед рассылкой и задержками для избежания бана от Telegram, но не совсем понимаю как правильно это сделать.

Текущий код рассылки, который совсем не устаивает:

```
elif call.data == 'send':
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM login_id')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    msg = 'текст рассылки'
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in result:
        bot.send_message(x[0], str(msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Для создания рассылки сохраняйте user_id в БД, после чего методом send_message отправляйте само сообщение-рассылку. Вот неплохое видел на этот счёт: [ссылка](https://youtu.be/Nuyr3a2dZ1c)

Если я Вас правильно понял, то Вам нужно осуществить некую задержку перед отправкой сообщения. Вы можете это сделать таким способом: Проверяете всех user_id входящих сообщений на наличие в вашей БД рассылки. Если да, то далее отправляете выше указанным метод сообщение.

Также советую прикреплять ваш код полностью или комментировать саму суть проблемы.

Comment: Немного непонятно, как сделать, чтобы у админа бот запрашивал текст рассылки перед её началом.
Не могли бы вы помочь подсказав код?

Видео смотрел ещё до вопроса и делал похожую рассылку, но там нет запроса текста перед рассылкой. Да и вместо БД используется текстовый файл :)

Comment: Если Вам надо получить  текст для рассылки у админа, то просто проверяйте user_id на id админа, если это его, то берите текст сообщения и вызывайте функцию рассылки с этим текстом.